# If file doesnt contain more than n lines change variable

Tags: python

I currently have some code that grabs all the lines after the first one in a file and saves it to the variable **resourceslist** . I want to add some code that says if there's  **only** one line in the file then give variable **resourceslist** the value "oneline"

```
with open('filepaths', "r+") as f:
            if index + 1 > len(f):
                for _ in range(1):
                    next(f)
                for lines in f:
                    resourceslist = f.read()
               else:
                   resourceslist = "oneline"
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. What is the `else` keyword supposed to be associated with: the `if` statement, or one of the `for` loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the following; your first `for` loop isn't necessary, as it will never actually loop, and the second one is unnecessary because you want to read the entire (remaining) contents of the file into `resourceslist`, without otherwise iterating over the remaining lines.

```
with open('filepath') as f:
    next(f)  # Skip the first line
    resourceslist = f.read()
    if not resourceslist:  # i.e., f.read() returned the empty string
        resourceslist = "oneline"
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Thank you very much. Will mark correct in 7 minutes, when i'm allowed to. :-)